# Devise: prevent multiple models signed in at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have two **completely separate** models Consumer and Shop (there's no STI and no User model).

Everything works right with Devise, except the fact that it "allows you to have multiple models signed in at the same time". Can I turn off this behaviour?

I'm looking for a way to prevent a user being logged in at the same time both as a Consumer and as a Shop. For example, if he's logged in as a Consumer, he must first log out before logging in again as a Shop.

How can I force that?

Comment: you need to do by your own. but if those are 2 different objects, it doenst make sense to me, that he can only be logged in once at a time.

Comment: better go STI and say, he needs to decide which frontent he wants to be logged in, either /store or /user

Comment: @huanson I don't use STI because the tables are very different and the queries always refer to one table or the other, but never to both. Also, it's true that they are different objects but some Devise methods, such as devise_parameter_sanitizer, are in common to all classes.

Comment: @huanson Even if I'll keep two separate tables, you're right on the fact that **there's no real problem in having two separate models** logged in at the same time. `devise_parameter_sanitizer` is in common, however you only use it in Devise controllers and in this case the routes always specify one model or the other (never both). The only oddity is that the front end becomes a sort of *mixin* when you're logged in both as a Consumer and as a Shop - but no one will do it in practice and in any case it will work (at most some poor UX).

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that there's no real problem in having two separate models logged in at the same time. In my case the only oddity is that the front end becomes a sort of mixin when you're logged in both as a Consumer and as a Shop - but no one will do it in practice and in any case it will work correctly.

However, just for reference, you can force sign out before any login by overriding the `Devise::SessionsController`'s `create` method.